# Regex - selecting in-between

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
c:\logs\xxxx\yyyy.log
```

Both "xxxx" and "yyyy" can be any strings of any length and any characters.

I need to select the "xxxx" part.
So far, I have the following regex:

```
[^c:\\logs\\](.*)[\\]
```

This outputs:

```
xxxx\
```

However, I'm having difficulties losing the last "\"

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `"xxxx"` and `"yyyy"` can be any characters ***except backslash***, this will match the `"xxxx"` part:

```
(?<=^c:\\logs\\)[^\\]*(?=\\[^\\]*\.log$)
```

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/bhADtaOx6p).

This regex matches all non-backslash characters that are preceded by `"c:\logs\"` and followed by non-backslash characters then `".log"`

By the way, your attempt of `[^c:\\logs\\]` is using a character class in the wrong way - `[^c:\\logs\\]` means "any single character that is not one of `c:\logs`"